# The Cython closure_freelist_size option

Tags: python, optimization, closures, cython, compiler-optimization

One of the more obscure Cython compiler options is `closure_freelist_size`, which defaults to `8`. According to the [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#Cython.Compiler.Options.closure_freelist_size), this is the

> number of function closure instances to keep in a freelist

What does this mean? What sort of code could benefit (performance-wise, even a little bit) from changing (lowering, I presume) this number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cython provides a `@cython.freelist` decorator that you can apply to `cdef class`es: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#fast-instantiation. The assumption it makes is that memory allocation is slow, and that the class its applied to typically has a few fairly short-lived instances at any one time. It therefore keeps memory for up to `N` instances of the class constantly allocated and allocates new instances in that memory if available. It also assumes that you won't inherit from the class (hence all allocations are the same size).

The cost is

1. A little higher base memory usage.
2. If the assumptions are wrong (for example if many more than `N` instances are typically in existence at once) then most allocations won't be able to take advantage of the freelist, and there will be a bit of time wasted deciding that.

Internally, Cython represents closures (i.e. variables captured in inner functions, generator expressions, generators, etc.) as `cdef class`es. The `closure_freelist_size` option applies the freelist optimization to these closures. For most use-cases it probably is applicable to these since you typically don't have huge numbers instances of a single generator in existence simultaneously.

If the assumptions don't apply then it may be worth turning off, or if you have an inner loop which allocates (say) 16 simultaneous instances of a single generator then it may be worth turning up. If you aren't using closures much then it probably doesn't matter.